# Fancy awk output without using printf

Tags: awk, gawk, nawk

This is just for curiosity.

I have a tab delimited file like this

```
jklh    banana  hk
hkl klh jklh
h   hk  banana
h   hk  kljh
asdf    banana  lk
sdfa    jklæ    jklæ
banana  sdf jklæ
```

By doing this I replace 'banana' in the first column and the output stays otherwise the same:

```
awk '{gsub(/banana/,0,$1)}; {printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n", $1, $2, $3}' file > outfile
```

This on the other hand replaces tabs with spaces in the line I replaced the word banana with 0:

```
awk '{gsub(/banana/,0,$1)}; {print}' file > outfile
```

How can I use `OFS` or something similar to print out the replaced line without replacing tabs. I've been playing around alot without progress. Remember: No `printf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `OFS` to a tab:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{gsub(/banana/,0,$1)}; {print}'
```

Comment: @AWE: Alternatives: You can use it without the `-v` by putting it at the end: `awk '{...}' OFS="\t" inputfile` or in a `BEGIN` block: `awk 'BEGIN {OFS = "\t"} {...}' inputfile`

Comment: Somehow I didn't stumble on any of the right alternatives when I was trying. I see now I was often close.